# docker-compose access ports externally

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm sure this question has been answered before, but I cannot find a simple solution anywhere. I have multiple `docker-compose` projects running on a single host, with unique host port mappings.

I'd like to access a Flask API from outside the server, but cannot work out how to do this. There seems to be an option when running `docker-compose run -p`, but I was of the understanding that `docker-compose up -d` is the preferred and robust way to run compose.

I tried changing `network_mode: "bridge"` to `network_mode: "host"`, but this didn't help.

Let's say the IP of the host is 123.23.23.111, I would like to access the `api` service externally via something like `http://123.23.23.111:5004`, as well as the Flower monitor via `http://123.23.23.111:5559`.

It's all running on a private network, and I would like another server on the private network to access the API, but no internet access is needed. https will be added later.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./api/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "5004:5000"
    network_mode: "host"
    depends_on:
      - redis
  worker:
    user: nobody
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./worker/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - redis
  monitor:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./monitor/Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "5559:5555"
    network_mode: "host"
    entrypoint: flower
    command: --port=5555 --broker=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
```

The Dockerfile in `api/Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

ENV CELERY_BROKER_URL redis://redis:6379/0
ENV CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND redis://redis:6379/0

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
ENV DEBUG true

COPY ./api/requirements.txt /api/requirements.txt
COPY .env /api
WORKDIR /api

# install requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# expose the app port
EXPOSE 5001

RUN pip install gunicorn

COPY ./api/app.py /api/app.py
COPY ./api/worker.py /api/worker.py

# run the app server
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "--workers", "3", "app:app"]
```

Also interesting:

```
sudo docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                          DRIVER              SCOPE
eb03130b85ea        bridge                        bridge              local
15f8a2e5cd21        host                          host                local
d80f015461c3        myapp_default                 bridge              local
0dd1b3ace731        none                          null                local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ports` should expose it the way you want if you leave `network_mode` out. Just don't set it to `host` or `none`. Also, make sure it's not your host's firewall preventing access.

> Port mapping is incompatible with network_mode: host

From: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/